# Which temperature to use for entropy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, entropy, thermal-conductivity

So in my textbook for the course it says "$T$ is the temperature at which heat is supplied to the
system."

and I thought I understood it but got confused when this question came up:

> $1 \ \mathrm{L}$ of water is heated from temperature $T_1 = 17^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$ to temperature $T_2 = 90^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$
> in a pan placed on a heating element (taken as a heat reservoir) at $T_H =
> 500^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$. Assuming negligible thermal expansion and that the heat capacity
> remains constant at $c = 4.18 \,\text{kJ K}^{−1} \text{kg}^{−1}$, find: (a) the entropy change in the water during this process (b) the entropy change in the heating element

I got the heat transferred with $đQ = C_v\, \mathrm dT$, and I used $T = 290\,\text K$ for water and $T = 773\,\text K$ for the heating element, and I feel like its wrong. Can anyone explain in a different way which $T$ to use?

Comment: Taking absolute zero as $-273^o$C then $T1=273+17=290$K and $TH=273+500=773$K. Whatever you "feel" is wrong, it is not in these temperature conversions.

Comment: Are you talking about which temperature to use in Clausius' inequality with the actual dQ or in calculating the entropy change using the dQ for a reversible path?

Comment: Show your calculations

Comment: @ChetMiller, to calculate entropy change.

Comment: @BobD, i got dQ = C*dT as 30.5*10^4 J, then for the water entropy, I used s = dQ/T = 30.5*10^4 / 290 K = 1052.2. for the heating element i used -30.5*10^4 / 773 K = -394.74, my main concern is whether I'm using the correct "T" for both parts

Comment: Please edit your question to include the calculation that you have provided.

Comment: @Luki1221 you can’t use a single temperature to calculate entropy change for the water since, unlike the heating element temperature reservoir, heat transfer to the water occurs over a range of temperatures.

Comment: For next year's resolution but immediately starting today promise yourself that you will always say mentally before asking a question related to *thermodynamics* as a starting step to understand this very confusing subject that "a thermal reservoir supplies entropy, a thermal reservoir does not supply heat, a thermal reservoir supplies entropy, a thermal reservoir does not supply heat,...". Never ever forget and just keep saying it!

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to just use the initial temperature of the water to calculate the entropy added to it.

The amount of entropy added to an object in an infinitesimal process is $dS = dQ/T$.  If these infinitesimal bits of heat are all added to (or removed from, if they're negative) a system whose temperature is effectively constant, such as a heat reservoir, then each little unit $dQ$ of heat leads to the same little unit of entropy change $dS$.  So it is not too hard to see that this implies that $\Delta S = \Delta Q / T$ as well.

However, if the temperature of the system changes during the process, then each infinitesimal $dQ$ of heat results in a different amount of entropy change.  So instead we have to add up all these infinitesimal bits of entropy added at all the different temperatures — in other words, we need to perform an integral to calculate $\Delta S$.

Answer (score 0):

> So in my textbook for the course it says "$T$ is the temperature at which heat is supplied to the system."

This is an incomplete quote that makes it impossible to tell what your textbook is referring to. Also, the title is about entropy, but the question at the end of the post is about heat (actually, enthalpy). But here is the general way to approach this type of problem:

- For water: If it is heated from initial temperature $T_{w1}$ to final temperature $T_{w2}$ (in kelvin), presumably under constant pressure, the governing equations are:
  $$
     Q_w = \Delta H_{12} = M_w C_P(T_{w2}-T_{w2}),\quad
     \Delta S_{12} = M_W C_P \ln\frac{T_{w2}}{T_{w1}}
  $$
- For the bath: the bath is losing heat $Q$ at constant temperature $T_\text{bath}$:
  $$
     Q_\text{bath} = - Q_w = - M_w C_P(T_{w2}-T_{w2}) \\
     \Delta S_\text{bath} = - \frac{Q_\text{bath}}{T_\text{bath}}
  $$
- Entropy generation: It is the sum of the entropy change of the system and the surroundings (bath):
  $$
     S_\text{gen} = \Delta S_{12} + \Delta S_\text{bath}
  $$
  and you should be able to show that this is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your equation is contained in the following rendering of the Clausius inequality for a closed system (such as the water in your example):  $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T_{B,rev}}}\geq\int{\frac{dQ_{act}}{T_{B,act}}}$$where $dQ_{rev}$ are the increments in heat for a reversible path between the actual initial and final states, $T_{B,rev}$ is the temperature at the boundary between the system and surrounding for a reversible path, $dQ_{act}$ are the increments in heat for the actual path, and $T_{B,act}$ is the temperature at the boundary between the system and surroundings for the actual path through which $dQ_{act}$ flows.  For the water in your system, the temperature at the boundary of the surroundings is reservoir temperature $T_{B,act}=773\ K$.

A reversible path between the initial and final states consists of one in which the boundary temperature is only slightly different from that of the system T over the entire process path.  This could be achieved by placing the system in contact with a continuous sequence of reservoirs running from the initial temperature to the final temperature.  So, for the case of your water, the entropy change would be $$\Delta S=\int_{290}^{363}{\frac{mC_vdT}{T}}$$